# How to get jqxGrid Current Sort Order?

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid

What is the programmatic method determine the current sort order of a jqxGrid?

I have a current requirement to implement sorts through a dropdown list and sort button combination rather than through the default column sorting.  It would be nice to automatically reverse the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use the jqxgrid API method `getsortinformation`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wf1rta2f/4/